# What is the location where default wallpapers are located in Manjaro XFCE?

Tags: xfce, manjaro, wallpaper

What is the location where default wallpapers are located in Manjaro XFCE? I tried looking into `/usr/share/xfce4/` but cannot find any wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

In Manjaro XFCE, all the default wallpapers are located at `/usr/share/backgrounds/`.